# NHibernate Assigned ID for parent and identity ID for child

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate. I have a parent class with Assigned ID and child class with identity Id. I create a new parent class, assign Id to it, then create a new collection of child object. When I call session.Save(parent), I found only parent object is saved, child collection is not saved. It seems that child object must also be saved one by one.

Sometimes I have reversed situation, parent with identity Id and child with assigned Id, also sometimes both parent and child are assigned Id.

I want to confirm is there any way that I always call Session.Save or Session.Update for parent, and NH can deal with the child collection automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need add some code to get help but just idea for you ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
 namespace="YourNameSpace" assembly="YourAssemblyName">



 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```